# Подскажите как лучше всего реализовать (collection view? или ваш вариант )

Tags: ios, mobile-development

Хочу сделать подобное приложение, в нем существуют категории затрат, при нажатии на категорию открывается редактор и добавляется значение. подскажите как лучше всего это сделать ? Реально ли сделать это с collection view? и нужно ли так вообще ? или просто outlet цеплять ?

[image: Макет приложения]

Answer (score 0):

Из идей, можно сделать верхний ряд коллекцией, а по бокам и центр в виде кастомки, т.е отдельные объекты, либо хорошенько поработать с кастомным `layout` - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html